# Gnome desktop symbolic link icon cannot change

Tags: gnome, desktop-icons

Is there a way to change the icon of a symbolic link on the gnome desktop?  I want to use a unique icon for the link to the Windows partition, however, simply going to properties and changing the icon does not actually change the icon on the desktop.

Comment: with 18.04, it works : icon of a symlink can be changed... How did you do ? What is your Ubuntu setup ?

Comment: Currently, I'm using 19.04. i attempted to change the icon right clicking on the icon and going to properties and changing the icon. Does the icon need to be a specific size? I have tried png and svg icons.